# How do I find a file whose name may be longer than the intended name?

Tags: regex, perl, file, search

I am doing some testing where I have a lot of files that I need to perform data analysis on. We have a naming convention with our files, but sometime someone will add a little more to the file name. I'm looking for a way to look for the "core" of the name and then save the entire file name.

For example, I want to find `WIRA_Rabcd_RT`, but someone may have saved the file name as `RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRA_Rabcd_RT.txt`, so my folder will look something like this:

```
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRB_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRC_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRA_Rabcd_RT.txt ← I want to find this file, and open it.
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRF_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRG_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRT_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRW_Rabcd_RT.txt
RED_GREEN_BLUE_WIRQ_Rabcd_RT.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function seems like it would do the trick:

```
my $dir = '/some/directory/';
my @files = glob($dir . '*WIRA_Rabcd_RT.txt');

# Make sure you get exactly one file, open it, etc.
```

Comment: What if i want to add a variable $dir (directories) in front of the WIRA_Rabcd?

Answer (score 0):

In Perl `TIMTOWTDI` so here is another way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = 'dirname';
my $pattern = 'WIRA_Rabcd_RT';

my @files;

{ 
  opendir my $dir_handle, $dir;
  @files = grep { /$pattern/ } readdir $dir_handle;
} #end-of-block autocloses lexical $dir_handle
```

`@files` now contains the names of the files in the directory that matches the pattern. Note that the names are relative to that directory (stored as `name` not `dir/name`). I often then use the [`File::chdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3achdir) module to change the working directory to `$dir` to work on those files. For example:

```
use File::chdir

# get @files in $dir as above...

{
  local $CWD = $dir;
  # work with files in @files
} 

# working directory restored to original here
```